# Standard way of getting a form inside block

Tags: 8, forms, blocks

I'm using :

```
public function build() {

    $form = $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\mymodule\Form\Myformclass');
    return $form;
  }
```

to get form inside block. But Drupal community doesn't find it as an appropriate way to get form inside a block.

According to Drupal community module reviewing team, Do not hard-code class names in strings. I tried calling class directly but that is not serving my purpose, giving 505 error.

What's the right way to get a form inside a block?

Comment: That's how I do it. I'm curious as to their reasoning behind their comments. Did they give any more comments and/or examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the fully qualified class name by using `ClassName::class`:

```
use Drupal\mymodule\Form\Myformclass;

  public function build() {

    $form = $this->formBuilder->getForm(Myformclass::class);
    return $form;
  }
```

If you want to avoid the full classname in code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help to load the custom form SampleDataForm defined on the path Drupal\mymodule\src\Form\ SampleDataForm.php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;


class MymoduleSearchBlockForm extends SampleDataForm 
{
  protected $formIdentifier;

  public function setFormIdentifier($formIdentifier)
  {
      $this->formIdentifier = $formIdentifier;
  }

  public function getFormId()
  {
    $form_id = 'sample_form';
    if($this->formIdentifier)
    {
        $form_id .= '-' . $this->formIdentifier;
    }
    return $form_id;
  }
}
```